# Scala/Java reflection array type

Tags: reflection

I am trying to instantiate case classes using reflection.
I am using this reference code: https://gist.github.com/ConnorDoyle/7002426

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object ReflectionHelpers extends ReflectionHelpers

trait ReflectionHelpers {

  protected val classLoaderMirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

  /**
    * Encapsulates functionality to reflectively invoke the constructor
    * for a given case class type `T`.
    *
    * @tparam T the type of the case class this factory builds
    */
  class CaseClassFactory[T: TypeTag] {

    val tpe = typeOf[T]
    val classSymbol = tpe.typeSymbol.asClass

    if (!(tpe <:< typeOf[Product] && classSymbol.isCaseClass))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "CaseClassFactory only applies to case classes!"
      )

    val classMirror = classLoaderMirror reflectClass classSymbol

    val constructorSymbol = tpe.declaration(nme.CONSTRUCTOR)

    val defaultConstructor =
      if (constructorSymbol.isMethod) constructorSymbol.asMethod
      else {
        val ctors = constructorSymbol.asTerm.alternatives
        ctors.map { _.asMethod }.find { _.isPrimaryConstructor }.get
      }

    val constructorMethod = classMirror reflectConstructor defaultConstructor

    /**
      * Attempts to create a new instance of the specified type by calling the
      * constructor method with the supplied arguments.
      *
      * @param args the arguments to supply to the constructor method
      */
    def buildWith(args: Seq[_]): T = constructorMethod(args: _*).asInstanceOf[T]

  }
}
```

Everything works great for most types of fields in the case class.
My only issue is when trying to populate array fields.

Basically it boils down to this issue:

```
case class MyClass(arr: Array[String])

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val f = new CaseClassFactory[MyClass]
    f.buildWith(Seq(Array[String]("1","2","3"))) //This works
    f.buildWith(Seq(Array[Object]("1","2","3"))) //This does not work
  }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaVanillaMethodMirror1.jinvokeraw(JavaMirrors.scala:415)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaMethodMirror.jinvoke(JavaMirrors.scala:380)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$JavaVanillaMethodMirror.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:396)
```

In my use case the array is being created using reflection as well as an Array[Object].
I have the scala.reflect.api.Types#Type of the array field of the case class. I need to somehow convert the existing array to one with the correct type
I understand the internal implementation of arrays causes the issue.
How can I convert the array to the needed type at runtime.
I tried to use Arrays.copyOf but did not get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by copying the array into another array of the correct type:

```
val arr: Array[Any] = ...
val correctTypeArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(theClass, arr.size).asInstanceOf[Array[Any]]
arr.indices.foreach(i => correctTypeArray(i) = arr(i))
```